# cakephp : cakephp pagination conditions

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

is this possibale to use below query in pagination conditions?

```
$data = $this->Product->query("select * from product_tbls where price >".$this->request->data["min"]." and price <".$this->request->data["max"]);
```

i tried this

```
$data = $this->Product->find('all');
    if(isset($this->request->data["min"]))
    {
        $this->paginate = array(
                            'conditions' => array('Product.price >' => $this->request->data["min"] ,'Product.price <'=>$this->request->data["max"]),
                            'limit' => 6,
                            'order' => array('id' => 'desc')
                            );
        $data = $this->paginate('Product');
    }
```

this is form

```
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><h5><b>Enter Price</b></h5></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="min" placeholder="Min" size="4"></td>
            <td><h5>To</h5></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="max" placeholder="Max" size="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="b1" value="Search"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

all i m using this code.
when is use that normal php query and don't use pagination i m getting all correct data as i perform search in from's text field

i m getting this on `debug($data);` if i search for 20000 to 30000

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Product' => array(
        'id' => '43',
        'category_tbls_id' => '3',
        'subcategory_tbls_id' => '22',
        'brands_tbls_id' => '0',
        'product_description' => 'product desc',
        'name' => 'Utsav Fashion Pink Net Saree',
        'price' => '22000',
        'photo' => '145500138232.jpg'
    ),
    'brands_tbls' => array(
        'id' => '0',
        'name' => 'no brand'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Product' => array(
        'id' => '26',
        'category_tbls_id' => '2',
        'subcategory_tbls_id' => '11',
        'brands_tbls_id' => '4',
        'product_description' => 'Product description here.',
        'name' => 'Spykar Jeans',
        'price' => '2400',
        'photo' => '14544135633.jpg'
    ),
    'brands_tbls' => array(
        'id' => '4',
        'name' => 'spykar'
    )
)
```

)

Comment: and what happened? did it work? it looks good!

Comment: i m doing it to search products between two price but its not working

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description! Please be more specific as to what _exactly_ happens, and what you'd expect to happen instead. Also show your debugging attempts (like, what does the query looks like that is being issued).

Comment: and whats the result, error or message?

Comment: sometime page reloads and sometime showing some products but not as i m trying to search

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? You may have forgotten the `AND` statement: ie. `'conditions' => [ 'AND' => [(min), (max)] ]`. My assumption is that the `Product.price` is being overwritten, but would need the version to verify.

Comment: version CakePHP 2.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using the **POST** method in your form, you may lose data when you go to the next page.

If you still want to use the POST method, you need to save data from your form in the session and use them on the next page.

You can also use the GET method, ([Read more](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters)) which will generate a url like:

```
products?min=2000&max=3000
```

In this case, instead of using a `$this->request->data` ,
you need to use `$this->request->query['min']` and `$this->request->query['max']` and and be sure to prevent SQL injection.

But why not try this plugin: https://github.com/CakeDC/search ?